# How to read user input in c# console

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I guess this should be very simple to you guys, but very difficult to me because im new to c#.

I have a simple "pacient" class.

```
public class Pacient {

public Pacient(string _name, string _lastName, DateTime _date, string _phone, string _email)
{
    name = _name;
    lastname = _lastName
    dateOfBirth = _date;
    phone_num = _phone;
    email = _email;
}


private string name;
public string Name {
    get {
        return name;
    }
    set {
        name = value;
    }
}
```

etc...

Now i want to read the input user types in console...

**How do i do that?** It works with pre-typed names, like shown bellow..

```
 Pacient John = new Pacient("John", " Doe ", new DateTime(1992,12,12) , " 045-999-333", "  example@example.com");
        John.Email = "example@example.com";
        John.Name ="JOHN ";
        John.LastName=" DOE ";*/
```

**To sum up**
When console opens, it should ask for a name. And when user types in the name, console should store the name into "name" and later display it.

Thank you guys!

Comment: I presume you also mean `'Patient'`? Just in case this was a grammatical error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One variable named `name` is not enough if you want to split it up into first and last name as provided in your example.

```
Console.Write("First name:");
var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Last name:");
var lastName = Console.ReadLine();

Pacient John = new Pacient(firstName, lastName, new DateTime(1992,12,12) , " 045-999-333", "  example@example.com");
John.Email = "example@example.com";
```

To print it:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}",firstName,lastName);
```

P.S. Pa**t**ient is spelled with T in English.

Comment: thanks, this works. And yes i know about "patient", it was just a "typo" from converting it from local to english :)

Answer (score 2):

Think you can find all the info you need right 
[here.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readline)

```
string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
```

Tip for the future: you already knew that this was called the console, because you used that word in the question. So looking for 'C# console read text' on Google would be a good way to answer this question yourself. (Note: this is not flaming, just some feedback for the next question)

Answer (score 1):

You can get user input via  `Console.Read();`

you need to get each user input

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name :");
string FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Console.WriteLine("What is your choice?:");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (line)

{

case "1": // Do Something
break;

case "2": //Do that
}
 while (line != "9");
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code to improve it's quality.